# SocketException when calling setNetworkInterface on a MulticastSocket with an IPv4-only interface

Tags: java, udp, multicast, java-15

After updating the Java version from 12 to 15, this code now throws a rather non-descriptive `SocketException` on Windows, but only if IPv6 is disabled on the `NetworkInterface`:

```java
NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
DatagramSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(65533);
((MulticastSocket) socket).setTimeToLive(128);
((MulticastSocket) socket).setNetworkInterface(networkInterface); // <-- Exception thrown here
```

This is the exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.setInterface6(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.setOption(DatagramChannelImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.setOption(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:418)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.setNetworkInterface(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:600)
    at java.base/java.net.MulticastSocket.setNetworkInterface(MulticastSocket.java:466)
    ...
```

However, if I create the `Socket` like this, no exception is thrown:

```java
NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
DatagramSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(
    new InetSocketAddress(Collections.list(networkInterface.getInetAddresses()).get(0), 65533));
((MulticastSocket) socket).setTimeToLive(128);
((MulticastSocket) socket).setNetworkInterface(networkInterface); // <-- No exception is thrown
```

Is this expected/intended behaviour? If so, is this documented somewhere?

---

This test script...

```java
System.out.println("Example 1");
try {
    NetworkInterface netIf1 = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    System.out.println(netIf1 + " " + Collections.list(netIf1.getInetAddresses()).get(0));
    DatagramSocket sock1 = new MulticastSocket(65533);
    ((MulticastSocket) sock1).setTimeToLive(128);
    ((MulticastSocket) sock1).setNetworkInterface(netIf1);
    System.out.println("Success");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
            
System.out.println("Example 2");
try {
    NetworkInterface netIf2 = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    System.out.println(netIf2 + " " + Collections.list(netIf2.getInetAddresses()).get(0));
    DatagramSocket sock2 = new MulticastSocket(new InetSocketAddress(Collections.list(netIf2.getInetAddresses()).get(0), 65533));
    ((MulticastSocket) sock2).setTimeToLive(128);
    ((MulticastSocket) sock2).setNetworkInterface(netIf2);
    System.out.println("Success");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

...prints the following statements to the console:

```
Example 1
name:eth8 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM) /10.240.10.193
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.setInterface6(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.setOption(DatagramChannelImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.setOption(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:418)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.setNetworkInterface(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:600)
    at java.base/java.net.MulticastSocket.setNetworkInterface(MulticastSocket.java:466)
    at com.example.MyApplication.createSocket(MyApplication.java:32)
Example 2
name:eth8 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM) /10.240.10.193
Success
```

Comment: Your two pieces of code are not equivalent. The first determines the IP address via which `join()`s will be sent. The second determines the IP address to which the socket is bound, i.e. the IP address via which it can receive. You need to show what the actual `NetworkInterface` obtained by your first piece of code is.

Comment: Hi, I have added more context to the second code example. The issue seems to go away when I use the `MulticastSocket` constructor with the `InetSocketAddress` with the interface IP as an argument. The network interface which is used in this example is my main ethernet adapter (the build-in Intel network chipset)

Comment: That's what you *think.* I am asking you for *facts.* You need to *print* the `NetworkInterface` in both cases.

Comment: I've added more code with some print statements :)

The network interface seems to be the same in both test cases.

Comment: Please print the IP address of the `NetworkInterface` in both cases.

Comment: I've added the IP address to the debug statements. It's the same in both cases.

Comment: When you use `new MulticastSocket(65533)` this creates a multicast socket bound to the wildcard address. Because your OS/machine supports IPv6 the underlying socket will be IPv6. When you then try to set the NetworkInterface to an interface on which IPv6 is disabled, it fails. The difference in behavior compared to Java 12 is probably an unintended side effect of JEP 373 https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/373

Comment: I've created this issue to track it:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8272476
There are a number of workarounds noted in the issue